# how to remove a file with no extension(binary executable) on github remote repo via git bash?

Tags: git, github, git-bash

Assume that I have a file without an extension (binary executable) in my root repo. I would like to know how to remove it via git bash.  For Example inside_git_repo:

```
> ls  
client  client.c  server  server.c
```

Notice that the server, client has not extension. I wanted to know if there is any way to delete them using the wildcard method `*`.

I have tried the following but it does not work:

```
> git rm --cached '\*.'
fatal: pathspec '*.' did not match any files
> git rm --cached '\*./'
fatal: pathspec '*./' did not match any files
```

Comment: why do you want to use `*`?

Comment: Unix file names don't consist of two parts ("name" + "extension") the way DOS file names do. That is, there's no "first eight characters are name, last three are extension"—the system does not store `README21.TXT` as `README21TXT` internally. Instead, the dot is just another name character, so a file can be named `this.is.a.file`. It doesn't have `.file` as an *extension*, it's just *named* `this.is.a.file`. You can, if you like, *pretend* that `.is.a.file` is an extension, but he OS doesn't impose that. The rest of the world is moving towards this system, it seems.

Comment: Note that MS-DOS really did store file names this way—eight-plus-three—and FAT file systems from the 1990s had both "long names" and derived "short names". This is *why* `*.` works the weird way that it does, matching file names that don't have dots in them, on some systems. Git and bash, being Unix-derived software, don't behave this way.

Comment: @bolov I wanted to use *. because I have created many such c executable files and have it scattered all over my repository 

I was hoping to make use of the below command to remove them recursively 
>git rm -r --cached *.

Comment: @AashutoshTaikar for the future, do not store binaries into git. Use `.gitignore`

Answer (score 4):

There's no need to use globs. Simply use the filenames:

```
git rm client server
```

> I wanted to know if there is any way to delete them using the wildcard method `*`.

A plain `*` glob without any `.` would match the file, but it would also match most of what's in your directory (basically anything that's not hidden—prefixed with `.` itself).

If you have a real need to do something like a wildcard and your files are executable you could try using `find`, for example:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -executable -type f -exec git rm --cached {} +
```

See `man find` for details about its many options.